# Live stream video saved as blank video on google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, agora.io

I am currently using Google cloud storage for my project and facing an issue while storing the video generated by Agora live streaming. The recording time is perfect and the video is accessible too, but the issue is regarding the blank video being saved to cloud. When I try to play/check the video from cloud it run for the actual time but only blank video with no sound.

Can you please let me know if any setting need to be done on the cloud storage console or any parameters need to be set on the Agora cloud storage request.

Comment: 1) check the Content-Type metadata for the object in Cloud Storage.

Comment: What to add in the content-type metadata ? can you please explain? @JohnHanley

Comment: The **content-type** tells the decoder how to process the file (video/audio). use the correct value for your media type. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata

Comment: Tried it but still blank video.